# Set fixed color for CKEditor content in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor, editor, ckeditor5

I have used  [**CKEditor 5 rich text editor component**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular).

I want to set fixed color for the body(**I mean, whatever the user paste or types in the editor, the text color will get converted to specific color**).

my text color must be for example red.

I do not want to allow users to change the color.
this is my toolbar.

[image]

I searched a lot but did not find any solution.

How can I do that ?